# In C# what is the meaning of 1 after IEnumerable in System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

What is the meaning of `1` after IEnumerable in: `` System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 ``

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is the generic arity of the type, or put another way, the number of type parameters a generic type supports. `IEnumerable<T>` supports a single type parameter. If you were to look at `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` you would notice an arity value of 2.

Answer (score 2):

Within the .NET type system, it is necessary that types have unique names.  Although it is only possible to create instances of bound generic types (e.g. `IEnumerable<System.Int32>` or `IEnumerable<System.String>`), the unbound generic type may be used in certain contexts.  Within the language C#, such type would be written as `IEnumerable<>` but within the type system it is notated as `IEnumerable~1` [~ used to avoid format problems].  Note that the name of the bound generic type starts with the name of the unbound type, so if the unbound generic were called `IEnumerable<>` within the type system, the name of the bound generic would have to start with `IEnumerable<>`, *including the back-to-back less-than-greater-than signs*.