# Entity framework back ticks in generated sql

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I was looking at the source code for entity framework at [this link](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=map.Add%28@%22Sum%28IEnumerable%601%3CDecimal%3E%29-%3EDecimal%22%2C%20SequenceMethod.SumDecimal%29%3B) and I noticed we have code such

```
map.Add(@"Sum(IEnumerable`1<Nullable`1<Single>>)->Nullable`1<Single>",
SequenceMethod.SumNullableSingle);
map.Add(@"Sum(IEnumerable`1<Double>)->Double", SequenceMethod.SumDouble);
map.Add(@"Sum(IEnumerable`1<Nullable`1<Double>>)->Nullable`1<Double>", SequenceMethod.SumNullableDouble);
map.Add(@"Sum(IEnumerable`1<Decimal>)->Decimal", SequenceMethod.SumDecimal);
```

What are the back ticks (e.g. `` IEnumerable_`1 ``)? The backticks in the code screws up everything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C# what is the meaning of 1 after IEnumerable in System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable\`1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768208/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-meaning-of-1-after-ienumerable-in-system-collections-gene)

Comment: @KenD thank you for the edit.  How do you format when the string has a backtick in it?

Comment: You're welcome - if there's a backtick in the snippet, just encapsulate it with double backticks. I have to admit, I had to go searching for this myself, and found the answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code